# Deny google indexing in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, search-engine

Is there a way to prevent search engines from indexing a site by modifying the ASP.NET Web.config file?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using [`robots.txt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Answer (score 2):

Not by modifying the `Web.config`, but you can create a `robots.txt` in the domain root directory. If you don't want that, you could also use `<meta>` tags. See

- http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html and
- http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html